# Why I have AttributeError in django-realtime

Tags: python, django, real-time

I use this framework https://github.com/anishmenon/django-realtime
I read solution and write this:

```
def index(request):
    post = Post.objects.get(id=1)
    print(post.title)
    ishout_client.emit(
        Post.title,
        'notifications',
        data={ 'test' : 'test' }
    )
    return render(request, 'index.html', { })
```

But i got this:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'read'
```

I just want write webapclication where I click button and another browser get console log 'clicked' for example.

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/tescik/

Django Version: 1.10.4
Python Version: 2.7.12
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'corsheaders',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'drealtime',
 'tescik']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 'drealtime.middleware.iShoutCookieMiddleware']


Traceback:

    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
      39.             response = get_response(request)

    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _legacy_get_response
      249.             response = self._get_response(request)

    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
      187.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
      185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

    File "/home/marek/tescior/mysite/tescik/views.py" in index
      19.         data={ 'test' : 'test' }

    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/drealtime/__init__.py" in emit
      87.         response.read()

    Exception Type: AttributeError at /tescik/
    Exception Value: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'read'


import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'b78yjnhx_j0s#x%nc)8h-(znk%)l(i9ze--$4!0xrw^nmvxihv'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'corsheaders',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'drealtime',
    'tescik',
]

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'drealtime.middleware.iShoutCookieMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'mysite.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "templates")],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],

        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'mysite.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

html

```
<head>
{% load drealtimetags %}
</head>

test
```

Comment: post the complete traceback. Also post the complete code

Comment: Do you mean the model of post?

Comment: traceback will be enough no need of model

Comment: I edited question

Comment: Post your settings.py and all the code in the script you mentioned above.

Comment: ok, edited. Do you know some easier way to use web-socet in django? I just want write application where someone write message and other user look it  
immediately.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure an object `Post` with `id=1` exists? 
Try `get_object_or_404()` method instead of `get()` to avoid such errors.

Comment: If an object with id=1 in Post model is not found then it will raise an `ObjectDoesNotExist` exception. This is not a correct answer. Try to post comment for making suggestion don't post answers here like that.

Comment: yes this post is there, if i use print function i get post

Comment: This not answer. This is, maybe, a comment. By the way, welcome to Stackoverflow.